# Unity3D draw GUI.Button over GUI.Window

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, depth

I want to draw a GUI Button on top of a GUI window that I have in my game, but no matter what I try the button always appears behind.

This is my Code:

```
 GUI.depth = -30;
        Rect navBackButton = new Rect(10, 10, 10, 10);
        // DRAW NAVIGATION BUTTONS
        if (GUI.Button(navBackButton, navBackButtonTexture))
        {
            // DO LOGIC HERE
        }

        GUI.depth = 10;

        topScrollRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, topScrollHeight);
        topScrollListSize = new Vector2(topScrollRect.width - 2*listMargin.x, topScrollRect.height - 2*listMargin.y);

        GUI.skin.window = topStyle;
        GUI.Window(0, topScrollRect, (GUI.WindowFunction)DoTopScrollWindow, "");
```

I have tried to draw the buttons before drawing the window, and the other way round, but both have the same result.

In this forum post (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/setting-depth-of-a-window.12554/), it says that any GUI control with a depth of less than 1 will appear in front of GUI Windows, but I have set my depth to -30 and still the button appears behind the Window.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to draw the button in `DoTopScrollWindow()`.

You shouldn't try to place the buttons "on top" of the window, you should put them "in" the window, as the window is your navigation button's parent, conceptually. Additionally, drawing them in the window means that you can take advantage of relative positioning and window resizing without having to write a lot of extra code.

[According to the docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Window.html), the parameter `func` in `GUI.Window()` is a function designed to display content inside the window.

In this case you want your buttons "inside" that window, so draw them in the function you pass in as `func`.